# assembly code about ret

Tags: assembly

I was debugging my code using gdb, and ran across this problem。
The gdb shows as follows:

```
(gdb) ni
0x08048ca5 in getbufn ()
(gdb) disas 0x08048c98
Dump of assembler code for function getbufn:
0x08048c89 <+0>:     push   %ebp
0x08048c8a <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048c8c <+3>:     sub    $0x208,%esp
0x08048c92 <+9>:     lea    -0x200(%ebp),%eax
0x08048c98 <+15>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048c9b <+18>:    call   0x8048bf4 <Gets>
0x08048ca0 <+23>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
=> 0x08048ca5 <+28>:    leave  
0x08048ca6 <+29>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) p /x $ebp
$1 = 0x55683950
(gdb) p /x $esp
$2 = 0x55683748
(gdb) ni
0x08048ca6 in getbufn ()
(gdb) p /x $ebp
$3 = 0x4030201
(gdb) p /x $esp
$4 = 0x55683954
(gdb) x /1xw $esp
0x55683954:     0x55683750
(gdb) si
Cannot access memory at address 0x4030205
(gdb)
```

The code in 0x08048ca6 is "ret", which means jmp(%esp), addl 0x4,%esp
So I wonders why the last sentence of gdb is "Cannot access memory at address 0x4030205"
Is it supposed to execute instruction code in address 0x55683750?

Thx!

Comment: +1 for actually using a debugger :) (unlike thousands and thousands of other questions!)

Comment: PS: the value 0x55683750 looks suspiciously like a text string: "Wh7P"

Comment: It is he `leave`, not the `ret` that crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Hi -

```
                     ; Enter subroutine: build stack frame
0x08048c89 <+0>:     push   %ebp            ; Save the old buffer pointer
0x08048c8a <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp       ; Save the current stack pointer
0x08048c8c <+3>:     sub    $0x208,%esp     ; Allocate space for local variables

0x08048c92 <+9>:     lea    -0x200(%ebp),%eax ; call "gets()" subroutine
0x08048c98 <+15>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048c9b <+18>:    call   0x8048bf4 <Gets>

0x08048ca0 <+23>:    mov    $0x1,%eax       ; eax <= 1

=> 0x08048ca5 <+28>:    leave  ; we *think* we're leaving the subroutine...but
0x08048ca6 <+29>:    ret       ; in fact we crash at this point
```

CONCLUSION:

Something in "gets()" trashed your stack, so you *can't* return from your subroutine.

SUGGESTION:

Don't use "gets()".  It isn't safe.  Most compilers will actually *WARN* you that it isn't safe.  Use "fgets()" (or any number of other alternatives for inputting a string) instead:

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/137352-gets-unsafe-method-alternatives.html

IMHO...

Comment: hi,paulsm4. I use gets() here because I am doing the buffer overflow experiment.I get the return address overwritten to 0x55683750, and I want to see the code to jump there via ret instruction. But it didn't

Comment: So you're trying to program a stack overflow exploit ;)?  Q: Are you sure that 0x55683750 (string "Wh7P") is a valid address?  ALSO: look here: http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/LEAVE

Answer (score 0):

The "=>" points to the instruction that is *about* to execute, which is "leave" in this case. And "leave" is defined to first set `esp` to `ebp`, then pop `ebp`. Once `esp` has been set to `ebp` (which is `0x4030201`, a bad address and something that looks suspiciously like it was generated from the bytes 1, 2, 3, 4), the pop fails.

You may want to look at the value of `ebp` before and after the call to `Gets()`. My guess is that the call to `Gets()` causes that register to be modified, which shouldn't happen as `ebp` is normally callee-save.

Note that while calling `Gets()` with a stack buffer of 512 bytes may not be advisable, it doesn't appear in this case that a buffer overrun is causing the crash. A buffer overrun could potentially make `ret` jump somewhere else, but it wouldn't cause `ebp` to be modified.